# mysql query: if expiry date = current date + redirect at login?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to add a query to my login that checks the 'subscription_expires' column in my sql table. This basically checks to see if a users membership has expired and if the date is the current date + then it should redirect to another page?

Here's my code but i don't know how i would go about checking if the subscription_expires date is the current date +

Could someone please show me how i might do this? Thanks.

```
// Check database to see if email and the hashed password exist there.
            $query = "SELECT id, email, close_account ";
            $query .= "FROM ptb_users ";
            $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
            $query .= "AND password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
            $query .= "AND close_account = '0' ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 1";
            $result_set = mysql_query($query);
            confirm_query($result_set);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) == 1) {
                // email/password authenticated
                // and only 1 match
                $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['id'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $found_user['email'];
                $_SESSION['sub_expires'] = $found_user['subscription_expires'];
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

                $result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online='Online' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
or die(mysql_error());



                redirect_to("dashboard.php");
```

Comment: Be aware that the `mysql_query()` function (along with all the other `mysql_xx()` functions) is being deprecated. It is not recommended for use -- in fact, it's been considered obsolete and insecure for years -- if at all possible, you should change your code to use the `mysqli_xx()` functions instead, or the PDO library.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this- (added subscription_expire in where condition)

```
// Check database to see if email and the hashed password exist there.
            $query = "SELECT id, email, close_account ";
            $query .= "FROM ptb_users ";
            $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
            $query .= "AND password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
            $query .= "AND close_account = '0' ";
            $query .= "AND subscription_expires < now() ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 1";
```

I assume that "subscription_expires" is a timestamp / datetime field.

Comment: @JohnJoseph - This is simply an example of implementing an additional clause to your SQL statement that will attempt to only select a record if the `subscription_expires` column value is less than the current timestamp.  As a result, it will only affect what data is returned.

Comment: ok sorry i got it to work, but do you know if theres a way i can say if this applies redirect to ....? please

Answer (score 0):

This would be the logic you need to accomplish a redirect based on a stored time.

**PHP**

```
// If you store a timestamp
$sub_time = $found_user['subscription_expires'];

// If you store a string date time
$user_time = new DateTime($found_user['subscription_expires']);
$sub_time = $user_time->format("U");

if($sub_time <= time())
{
    // Assuming this function works
    redirect_to("mypage.php");
}
```

**Explained**

I provided a tool for both a stored unix timestamp and a stored datetime. Basically we validate that the subcription time is less than or equal to the current time (which means expired) and use your redirect function to send them off.

Comment: i've tried putting this in as an else statement is this right? but when i do that it still lets the user log in.

Comment: @JohnJoseph I'm not sure I understand your question. You might want to add `die();` after the `redirect_to` to stop the code execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your redirect function consists of, but you can use header() to redirect the user accordingly.

This code:

```
$_SESSION['sub_expires'] = $found_user['subscription_expires'];
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

would be replaced with:

```
$_SESSION['sub_expires'] = $found_user['subscription_expires'];

if($_SESSION['sub_expires'] <= time()){
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}else{
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
}
```

This modification will result in redirecting the user and exiting the page if the expiration time is <= to the current time.  Otherwise, the user is still logged in so proceed accordingly and set the `logged_in` session variable.